# Writing to global file with threads in C

Tags: c, file-io, pthreads

I'm having an issue with being able to write to a file I've created globally, initialized in main (successfully), and writing to in a function used by multiple threads (on Linux).

```
#includes

FILE *f;
main(){
    // Create threads successfully
    f = fopen("fileName.txt", "w");
    // Make sure the file was able to be created
    if(f = NULL){
          printf("Unable to create file");
          exit(1);
     }
     // This much works, the check indicates the file was created 
     // successfully when I run it
     while(1){
         // loops for a while, getting input from user to direct threads
         // When end is determined, waits for all the threads to finish,
         // clears allocated memory, and closes file then returns
         fclose(f);
         return;
     }


}

void *threadProcess(){
    // Do stuff
    // This printf works fine using the values i give the function, as is here
    // The values are determined in 'Do stuff'
    printf("%d trying to write \"%d BAL %d TIME %d.%06d %d.%06d\" to the file\n", cid, tmp->reqNum, balance, tmp->seconds, tmp->useconds, endTime.tv_sec, endTime.tv_usec);
    fflush(stdout);

    // There appears to be a Segmentation fault here
    fprintf(f, "%d BAL %d TIME %d.%06d %d.%06d\n", tmp->reqNum, balance, tmp->seconds, tmp->useconds, endTime.tv_sec, endTime.tv_usec);
    // Never gets here
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  As I said, the printf statement right before the fprintf statement works and outputs the correct stuff.

Am I wrong to assume that would ensure I don't have an pointer issues for fprintf?

Thanks

Comment: You did omit almost all of the code. Perhaps the problem is in the code that we cannot see.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes because it's about 600 lines of code. I really don't think it is with the other code as all my testing has led to the fprintf. I've also just tried locking the statement with a mutex and that doesn't fix the problem. With that being said, pretend **threadProcess** is just a helper function. Would I be writing to/using the global file correctly then?

Comment: Well good luck then. If I were you I would create an SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I've figured out that it's an issue with the FILE. Because **f** is NULL when I check it right before the fprintf. So it seems like I'm not using the global file correctly.

Comment: In other words, the problem is with the code that we cannot see

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually no, it was in my _if(reqLog **=** NULL)_ check.... I was assigning not comparing. Sorry to have wasted your time haha.

Comment: Exactly. Code that we could not see. Lesson here is to make SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was in the code I included. 4th line of main.

Comment: You said if(reqLog.... I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

it was in my `if(reqLog = NULL)` check.... I was assigning not comparing. Sorry to have wasted your time haha. –  tompon